# Specify the classes of the following Markov chains, and determine whether they are transient or recurrent

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

Specify the classes of the following Markov chains, and determine whether they are transient or recurrent:
$$\mathbb{P}_1=\begin{Vmatrix}0 & 1/2 & 1/2\\ 1/2 & 0 & 1/2\\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0\end{Vmatrix},\quad\quad \mathbb{P}_2=\begin{Vmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{Vmatrix}$$
$$\mathbb{P}_3=\begin{Vmatrix}1/2&0&1/2&0&0\\1/4&1/2&1/4&0&0\\1/2&0&1/2&0&0\\0&0&0&1/2&1/2\\0&0&0&1/2&1/2\end{Vmatrix},\quad \mathbb{P}_4=\begin{Vmatrix}1/4&3/4&0&0&0\\1/2&1/2&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&1/3&2/3&0\\1&0&0&0&0\end{Vmatrix}$$

**My Attempt**

- $\mathbb{P}_1$: Closed class: $\{0,1,2\}$. All states are recurrent.
- $\mathbb{P}_2$: Closed classes: $\{0,1,2,3\}$. States 0 and 1 communicate with state 3, which communicates with state 2, which communicates with states 0 and 1 again. Thus, all states are recurrent.
- $\mathbb{P}_3$: Closed classes: $\{0,2\},\{3,4\}$ because states 0 and 2 communicate with each other and states 3 and 4 communicate with each other. Open class: $\{1\}$ because state 1 communicates with 0 but 0 does not communicate with 1. State 1 communicates with 2 but 2 does not communicate with 1. States 0, 2, 3, and 4 are recurrent. State 1 is transient.
- $\mathbb{P}_4$:
  Closed classes: $\{0,1\},\{2\}$ because states 0 and 1 communicate with each other, and state 2 communicates with itself.
  States 0 and 1 are recurrent, states 2, 3, and 4 are transient.

Can I get a formal and an intuitive definition of open and closed classes? I was able to figure this problem out from the patterns I have seen, but I would love to have a definition to go by.

I am not entirely sure if I did this correctly, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In your second Markov chain, there is one closed communication class. All states communicate. If the system is ever in state 0 or state 1, it transitions to state 3.  When in state 3, it always transitions to state 2. When in state 2, it transitions to either state 0 or state 1 with equal probability.  A closed class is one that the system cannot leave once it enters.  For example, in the fourth example, state 2 is in a closed communication class by itself. If the system is ever in state 2, it will never leave. Based on this comment, you should redo this problem and ask to be checked again.

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I made the corrections you suggested. I think I got the transient and recurrent parts correct though, right? Recurrent means that you can return to that state infinitely and transient means you only return to it a finite number of times?

Comment: An unrelated question, but on topic: If a Markov chain has an absorbing state (i.e. once you get there, you are stuck there), does that mean that the entire process is transient because there is 0 probability of visiting another state? Or do we just care about whether or not a state is transient, not the entire process? Thanks

Comment: In example 2, all states communicate with each other. $i$ and $j$ "communicate" does ***not*** mean that the chain can transition directly from $i$ to $j$ in one transition; it means that the chain has positive probability of transitioning from $i$ to $j$ (and from $j$ to $i$) in a finite number of steps.  A state is recurrent if, once in it, the probability that the system will return to that state in a finite number of steps is 1. Otherwise the state is transient. States are recurrent or transient, not the entire process.

Comment: In example 3, state 1 does not "communicate" with state 0. "communicate" is an equivalence relation.  If state $i$ communicates with state $j$, then state $j$ communicates with state $i$. See my last comment for the definition. The communication classes form a partition of the states. Each state is in exactly one communication class.